# How to hide an intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using an activity to show Pdf in android but whenever I use it another application will install to the phone. The new app will allow user to use that module to open pdf too, that I dont want. how can i prevent this.

i use this code to run the activity but i forgot where i got the resource which was  long time ago:

```
final File file = new File("/sdcard/anyfile.pdf");              
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.artifex.mupdf", "com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set this action for intent:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

It will try to show all application which have intent filter for this action. Remove this and just launch your activity.

Comment: It dosent work and i get error, should i change the androidManifest too? this is part of my AndroidManifest `<activity android:name="com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:background="@android:color/white" android:label="Android PDF Reader">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`

Comment: I tested below code also but cannot run the activity, do you have any idea? **`ComponentName lComponentName= new ComponentName(activity, MuPDFActivity.class);

         try {
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             i.setData(uri);
             i.setComponent(lComponentName);
             i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
             activity.startActivity(i); `**

Comment: Yes. remove "<intent-filter>                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> " from manifest as well and try. keep the intent action as Intent.ACTION_MAIN.